# Not able to launch workspace with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am new to mac(OS X). I have installed Java and other mandatory setting as environment path" etc. are done. But I am not able to launch workspace using Eclipse.

Steps done:

1. Downloaded Eclipse (tried with latest and the slightly older one : neon)
2. Unzipped the launcher
3. Clicked on the launcher and done the necessary steps
4. till the step , it ask to set the workspace, everything works fine. But after choosing or keeping the default workspace, following error appears.

The log file created is empty.

[image: Error_while_launching_workspace]

Comment: You need to dump the content of that error log file here.

Comment: Are you sure the log file is empty? Note, the log file is `.log` (not `.log.`).

Comment: Yes it is .log file which I referred. But for Oxygen eclipse version no .log file get created. However for Neon version empty log file get generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)** because you probably are using **Java 9** (the recent Eclipse Installer is based on Oxygen.1a, which explains why the installer works in contrast to your Eclipse IDE).

If this does not work, try to **start Eclipse with the option `-clean`** or open a new workspace (`-data ...`).

Comment: I have tried this version as well but same error occurs and no .log file get created.

Comment: Did you try it with an existing or a new workspace (`-data ...`)? Try to start Eclipse with `-clean`.

Comment: Thanks Howlger. This worked for me. I tried to open existing workspace. Which launched successfully.